# Diffusion coefficient of cells in blood?

Tags: cell-biology, hematology, biophysics, blood-circulation

What's the diffusion coefficient of white cells in blood?
Is it well defined, or are cells too large and few as to be treated as particles in this context?

P.S. I have tried to look this up, but what I find inevitably is about diffusion coefficients of molecules *inside* cells, which is not what I want.

Comment: Cells in blood flow will in the first approximation follow the flow. Of course blood flow is very complex and includes many interactions, so there'll be some kind of 'effective diffusion' arising from this, which will depend on many parameters (such as the flow velocity, pulsatility, hematocrit...)

Answer (score 2):

Cells absolutely can be considered as diffusing objects.  However, the origin of the "diffusion" can be very different than for, say, a bead in water.  The reason is that the thermal motion that creates the diffusion of a micron-sized bead can be much less important for a (large) cell.  For instance, the diffusion coefficient due to thermal forces of a sphere in a fluid with viscosity $\eta$ is
$$D_{therm} = \frac{k_B T}{6 \pi \eta R}$$
where $R$ is the cell radius (this is the "Stokes-Einstein" result).  For a white blood cell (say 10 microns in radius), this would - assuming blood is at least as viscous as water - lead to thermal diffusion coefficients around 1 microns$^2$/hour- i.e. we would need many many hours for a cell to travel its own diameter.  This result neglects a bunch of complexities - blood is not perfectly viscous, there is a really high density of red blood cells in blood, etc... but the basic result is that the thermal buffeting that drives the diffusion of a colloidal bead is not enough to drive a cell.

However, cells are not passive beads!  They crawl, both randomly, and (as cancerconnector notes), in response to signals like chemical gradients.  If a cell crawls with a speed $v$ and maintains its orientation over a time $\tau$, it's reasonable to describe its motion (over times much longer than $\tau$ as being diffusive with an effective diffusion coefficient
$$D_{motility} = \frac{1}{2} v^2 \tau$$
which you can get mostly from dimensional analysis, or more rigorous models.  For white blood cells, $v$ is on the order of microns/minute - at least when measured on slides - it might be different in the body.  $\tau$ is a few minutes, so $D_{motility}$ is on the order of many microns$^2$/minute - orders of magnitude faster than mere thermal diffusion.

A good introduction to modeling of this question is probably chapters 9-11 of Leah Edelstein Keshet's "Mathematical Models in Biology" and she cites some classic Lauffenberger papers on macrophage response, etc.  You may have access to this online: http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/1.9780898719147

Also, note that everything I've said so far neglects blood flow - if this is important in your problem (which will depend on the context), things can get more complex (have to include flow in your diffusion equation).  But using diffusion equations to model the spread of randomly motile cells is a very common approach, and there is a lot of literature on it!

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question because white blood cells do exhibit chemo and haptotactic responses, and also because of their large size - though cells are often modeled as moving by diffusion (cancer cells in particular, see: "[Modelling biological invasions: Individual to population scales at interfaces](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022519313002646)" as one of MANY examples). One could model their movement in a dish, and come up with a diffusion coefficient, but I'm not sure what the utility of this would be. Why do you want to know?  Is there another underlying question?

Comment: No underlying question. I am developing a mathematical model of cells in plasma. Just need some order of magnitude estimate.